# MariaDB and Microsoft SQL Server on Same Server

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

Are there any known issues with installing MariaDB on to a Windows Server which is already running MS SQL Server 2008 R2?

I need the two to safely work and co-exist with each other.

Thanks.

Comment: I have used both on same machine for small projects (like university course works) but cannot guarantee what is going to happen on production environment.

Comment: Easiest to find out: create a VM and install both. And make sure they're not using the same ports.